# Bootable pendrive

Tags: live-usb, disk-image

I was creating a bootable pen drive from Ubuntu disk image and before creating my C drive had a space of approx 3GB. The disk image took a space of approx 1.4GB in C drive and when I was finished creating the bootable pen drive using the rufus application suddenly the free space in C went from 3GB to 270MB!!
Could anyone explain me why this happened and where did ~2.7GB space went.

Answer (score 0):

Application you use to create bootable usb, creates partitions on USB drive. You can check it using Disk Utility. You can edit/delete those partitions or format partitions.

Comment: As you said , the partition would be created in USB drive but how come in my C drive space went down by 2.7GB ?

Comment: software you used did those changes.  Check partitions with Disk Utility.

Comment: Is there a way to attach an image here?

Comment: @RAMJASHNANI, Yes, edit your original question. At the top of the editing window there are icons for standard tasks. One of them is a landscape. Click on it to open a window, and from a file browser window you can drag and drop an image file into that window.

Answer (score 0):

**Why ~2.7GB space went:**

3 Gigs of space is a very minor fluctuation to notice when using the computer.  It will go up and down during normal operation.

The problem you are seeing is not from the actual space on the Pendrive.  The details you are explaining is from using the computer in general.  The computer requires both Hard Drive and Ram space to operate.  3 Gigs of fress hard drive space is not enough for Windows to operate.  If you have zero bytes of free space your system would fail.

When the computer is operating it uses your hard drive for many components of operation.

There are a number of **TEMP** folders that are used by Windows during normal operation.  Some of the files in the temp folders are automatically cleaned out and the space is recycled.  Some aren't automatically cleaned out and needs to be cleaned manually.  Right-clicking on your drive C: device will give you an option to check the space used by some of these elements and also give you the option to manually restore the space.

Mounting an external drive also uses hard drive space for buffering while it's mounted.  When you unmount the device the buffered space is written to the external drive (CD Drive, DVD drive, USB Pen Drive, etc).  That is why you have the eject option which should be performed before ejecting an external drive so that the buffer can be flushed and updated to the device before it's removed.  Removing the drive before executing the eject option can result in data loss to the external drive for this reason.  Even your internal hard drives take up buffering and cache space.

**Microsoft recommends a minimum of 20 GB for running Windows.**

[Windows system requirements](https://support.microsoft.com/en-us/help/10737/windows-7-system-requirements)

Other things that cause fluctuation to your hard drive space includes:

**Taking up space:**

```
Temporary files
    Temporary Internet Files
    Offline Web pages
    Browser History
Log Files
System Restore Points and Shadow Copies
Hard Drive Buffering and cache
```

While your Pen Drive drive is mounted it will be buffered by the Operating system.  After you eject it, it will no longer use space on your computer.